# What if your question is closed for being unclear and actual experts understand it and may know the answer?

Tags: discussion

What does it mean if your question is closed for being unclear and actual experts understand it and may be able to answer it?

This has happened to me!

Comment: Which question are you referring to?

Comment: If this is truly the case, post the question here and ask the person who is an expert to explain why it is a good question and then the community can come together and decide whether or not we should reopen it based off of the merits of that person's argument.

Comment: I made an edit to hopefully clarify the question. If I did not actually clarify your intent, do not hesitate to edit it further or roll back my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Questions are closed because five users with [enough reputation](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) (at least 500) vote to close them.  If one doesn't have enough reputation one can also [flag the question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) claiming it should be closed.  There may be other ways this can happen.

So, that is all it means. Votes to close need not come from experts. They come from active users with adequate reputation and a desire to cast that kind of vote.

You also will soon have enough reputation to cast close votes yourself if you stay active on the site and I hope you do stay active. What that means is the users who cast those close votes are as expert as you are.

At 500 reputation you will also have the privilege to cast votes on the close and reopen queues. On the close queue, you can also vote to leave the question open.

As far as finding an expert who knows and is willing to answer the question it may take continuing to ask questions hoping that expert may see the question and be motivated to answer it.